# find a number in another number without using Array

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

Recently i attended an interview where i was asked to write a function to find a term in a number and the number of times it occurs.

Lets say term = 51, number = 164518351, so 51 does exits in number and it occurs for 2 times, so return 2.

**My Solution** - Convert the number and term into string and , replace term string with "A" in the number string and then finally count the number of "A" in the number string. He asked me to solve without using strings, so i gave an array approach.

But he said that i cannot use arrays as well. so i want to know if there are other ways to do this ? I don't want the exact code or algo i just want to know various approaches we can take to solve this problem in minimum time complexity.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `mod/div 10` approach to read out single digits from the end of an integer?

Comment: I need an approach like what other thing we can do to solve it . I gave Strings , Arrays solution my codes worked fine  ,but he needed other approaches to solve this particular problem . . @SeekAddo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
int term_count = 0;
while(number > 0){
    if(number % 100 == term)
        term_count++;
    number = number/10
}
```

This will check if the last two digits of the number is equal to the term, and continue doing so ignoring every unit digits of the number.

something like this

> 164518351 % 100 == 51
>
> 16451835 % 100 == 51
>
> 1645183 % 100 == 51
>
> 164518 % 100 == 51
>
> ....

of course, here i know that the term is two digits and so i mod by 100. if you don't know that, you can find the number of digits in the term and then mod number by

> 10^(num_of_digits_in_term)

you can find the number of digits like this

```
int tempTerm = term, termDigitCount = 0;
while(tempTerm > 0){
    termDigitCount++;
    tempTerm /= 10;
}

// 51 > 0 -> termDigitCount = 1
// 1 > 0 -> termDigitCount = 2
// 0 > 0 -> exit while loop
```

and in the end if the term_count is 0, then there is no occurrence of the term in the number

Hope this helps.

P.S - the solution may not be syntactically correct since OP does not want an exact answer. just the logic.

Comment: what if the number is dynamically entered ? how can you write a static mod division function for that purpose ? What if he enters term=512 , and number=36512723512

Comment: All you need to do is calculate the number of digits of the term, which should be quite easy. And then divide with 10^pow where pow = number of digits of term.

Comment: the test of the while is incorrect as you will never reach 0 it should be number > 1

Comment: ^ 1/100 will be zero and hence it will exit the while loop. @VivekVashishta - will update the solution for a dynamic term